# Vue js should I filter objects in js or at my backend and make xhr to get results?

Tags: vue.js

Let's say I have table with 2 columns:
PROJECTS, TASKS
Project can have many tasks.
And lets say that I will have up to 15 000 tasks
So imagine: I click on projects1 from the first column => I should see in the second column all the tasks that belong to this project.

Should I make an xhr via api to get data, or should I store everything in a json on front-end and filter with js?
something like this structure:

```
[{project_name: 'some_project', tasks[{id:1, name:'dosomething'},{},{}]}
```

What will be faster? And what is reccomended?

Comment: By nature, client shouldn't have the task to filter information, and it's a bad bad idea to store the whole information inside the client and just filter.

Imagine you store 350 MB of information in the client instead of storing 5MB... Now imagine filtering 350 MB of information in the client side...

So yes, all filtering should be done in the server side. It's a very bad practice to bring thousands and thousands of information and process it in the client side to only show 100 or 1000, and information should be refreshed every time, but you can play with it. 
Search: Dynamic Programming

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad idea to filter information in the client, it should just display the data sent by the server, because backend tools are designed to fetch and process data and are better for this purpose.